# .NET Framework runs some code on GPU on my behalf

Tags: c#, .net, gpgpu

Hy,

I am currently looking at some code that need to be optimized. During my investigations I found that some levels takes few minutes to process whereas someothers take few hours. (All level are equivalent in size/number of objects and points). Noticing this, I search for answers and find out that during processing of the quick levels the GPU is used up to 30% whereas for the others the GPU is not used.

The code is written in c# and use the NetTopologySuite for Geometry ops (in case this can help). I am not using any lib to explicitly run code on GPU so I do not understand why some levels use the GPU (even if this is better for me). My research indicate that PLink only use CPU cores and I can not imagine that Windows could by itself decide to run some code on GPU instead of CPU (not same instructions, etc). 
Further investigations show me that even on fast levels the GPU is not used during the first seconds (10-20s).
From the previous point and because it depends on the level I guess that this is a runtime dependant decision made by the .NET framework (based on some statistics on the first iterations of the loop ?). 
So here are my questions : Is my deduction correct ? Can I influence the manner to dispatch code execution between CPU and GPU ?

Thank you for your help and do not hesitate to ask for more details if needed.

```
private void ProcessLevels(){
    _indexList.ForEach(i => ProcessLevel(levels[i]);
}

private void ProcessLevel(MyLevel level){
   level.RetrieveLotsOfObjects()
        .WhereNotNull()
        .AsParallel()
        .WithDegreeOfParallelism(n)
        .ForAll(o =>
                {
                     PerformComputation(o)
                });
}

private void PerformComputation(MyObject o){
    var pointsStatus = o.GetPointsStatus();
    ConcurrentBag<Points> safePoints = new ConcurrentBag<Points>();
    foreach (var pS in pointsStatus){
       if(pS.Status == Status.OK)
              safePoints.Add(pS.obj);
       else if (pS.Status == Status.Conflict)
              _suspiciousPoints.Add(pS.pt);
    }

    foreach (var point in safePoints){
        PerformGeometryOps(safePoints);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you showing these results, either intermediate or final? WPF and UWP are all GPU-based (DX9.0c and D3D11, respectively). WinForms technically not, but it still can use GPU for some stuff.

Comment: And also, since your code runs that slow, have you tried profiling? In VS2017 click “Debug / performance Profiler…”, check “CPU Usage” and click “Start”. Works equally well for C# and C++.

Comment: @Soonts The app is using WPF for the UI but here I am purely doing some geometric ops on data not link with the UI.

Comment: If you’re using WPF’s stuff for these geometric ops, it may upload data to GPU. Anyway, just run the profiler once and it will tell you where are you spending that time.

Comment: I have already spent some time in the profiler and can not squeeze things further but it do not resolve my issue. I think that I need to find a way to force the GPU to be used or to determine what factor influence its used in order to produce input data that will be launch to the GPU.